# How to validate PHP file syntax? without exec("php -l '$file'

Tags: php, lint

**I need an alternative way to check my file's PHP syntax.**

I am currently using this command to validate some PHP files.

```
$op=null; $ret=null; exec("php -l '$file' 2>&1",$op,$ret);
```

It runs fine on multiple linux and windows machines.
Unfortunately on shared hosting it fails with :

```
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [php -l '/path_to_the_file.php' 2>&1] in /my_program.php on line 559
```

Same thing happens with shell_exec() and system().

BTW `exec("echo '$file'",$op,$ret);` works fine, therefore I must conclude that the host disabled only certain commands (e.g. php).

What alternatives are there without having to install third-party plugins and commands? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the various solution presented when searching the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+unable+to+fork

Comment: Or google for `PHP lint` and see what comes up I suppose.

Comment: @Sammitch The error is specific to the particular command which I can no longer use. I need an alternative which does not involve installing third party software. Something native to default PHP installation.

Comment: @ficuscr I have checked and nothing. I am out of ideas. Maybe I should just check if the command line is available and if not avoid running the exec (otherwise 500 error).